# Django : What is the best way to Generic list (Product) and detail view (Category)

Tags: python, django

**It is better to use class based view or function view?**

**use get_absolute_url or slugify?**

How to use for and if to display categories in the menu?

Some issues are really confusing And it is impossible to understand which way is the best

**views.py:**

```
class ProductView(ListView):
    template_name = 'main/Html/html_components.html'
    model = Product


class ProductCategoryView(DetailView):
    model = ProductCategory
```

**url:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', ProductView.as_view(), name='Product'),
    path('category/', ProductCategoryView.as_view(), name='category-detail'),
    # path('<int:pk>/', ProductCategoryView.as_view(), name='category-detail'),
    # path('category/<slug:slug>/', ProductCategoryView.as_view(), name='category-detail'),
]
```

**html:**

html(for loop)

```
{% load static %}

<nav class="menu__main">
    <ul class="menu">
        {% for ProductCategory in ProductCategory %}
        <li class="single">
            <a href="" class="single__link">
                <span class="single__text">{{ ProductCategory.title }}</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="active dropdown__link">
                <span class="dropdown__text">Forms</span>
                <svg class="dropdown__arrow"><use href="#arrow-down"></use></svg>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown__list">
                <li class="dropdown__list__item">
                    <a href="" class="dropdown__list__link">
                        <span class="dropdown__list__text">Checkbox</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown__list__item">
                    <a href="" class="dropdown__list__link">
                        <span class="dropdown__list__text">Radio</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**models:py**

```
class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, unique=True, verbose_name='Title')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=300, blank=True, unique=True, verbose_name='slug')
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Create Date')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Category'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False, unique=True, verbose_name='Title')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=300, allow_unicode=True, null=False, blank=False, unique=True, verbose_name='slug')
    category = models.ForeignKey('ProductCategory', null=True, blank=True, db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Category Parent')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Product'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Please tell me the best solution for speed and optimization?

Answer (score 2):

'Better' is a relative term. In terms of speed and optimisation, as in system performance, there's no real difference between Class based and Functional views.

Which is right could depend on what you are planning to do.

If you just want to get set of barebones CRUD pages up and running as soon as possible, Class based views will help you get there with less code.

If you want to understand Django and how it works, I'd recommend learning functional views first as they make views a little more human-readable for beginners. This will also help you appreciate what class-based views bring to the table. Ultimately, you may end up using a mixture, so knowing the parts and patterns, strengths and weaknesses of each approach will be an advantage.

**slugs and urls**

A slug is simply a human-readable line of text that can be used as part of a URL, so you can use `mysite.com/product/big-chest-of-drawers` rather than `mysite.com/product/324`.  This is a useful approach for search engines and occasionally security (as you can't browse objects like Users simply by inputting id numbers.

get_absolute_url is a method attached to a model, so that you can simply call it in order to get the correct link for a modelinstance.

To put the two together, if your urls.py has:

```
path('products/<slug:slug>/', ProductView.as_view(), name='product-detail')
```

then you can use in your model:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return f"/products/{self.slug}/"
```

and then call in your templates:

```
<a href="{{product.get_absolute_url}}">{{product.name}}</a>
```

Now, if you ever want to change the URL pattern, you only need to change the first two lines and every template will still show the correct url on your site.

Finally, for and ifs in templates work like this - make sure your For variable is different from the name of your Queryset:

```
{% for productcat in ProductCategory %}
   {% if productcat == "fish" %}
      <p>This is a fish</p>
   {% elif productcat == "fowl" %}
      <p>This is a fowl</p>
   {% else %}
      <p>This is neither fish now fowl</p>
   {%endif %}
{% endfor %}
```